# Spring REST Controller Mapping Based on Parameter Value

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

In a Spring REST controller, is it possible to have a handler method based on a request parameter value?

For example I want the handler method to be invoked only when the value of the `type` parameter is product.

```
http://localhost:8080/api/vi/catalog?type=product
```

Comment: It's possible if you add a if (param.equals("product") {...} in  the method. Or are you referring to have a method just with that parameter?

Comment: You want to have different controller methods for different paramter value??,you can have different methods for different param like `http://localhost:8080/api/vi/catalog?type=product` can have method A and `http://localhost:8080/api/vi/catalog?ty=product` can have method b`

Answer (score 4):

This can be implemented in Spring MVC with the [`params` attribute of `@RequestMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params()), e.g.

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/catalog", params = "type=product")
public List<Product> getProducts() {
  ...
}
```

You can also do the inverse, i.e. `params = "type!=product"` to match all other types.

Answer (score 2):

Spring only matches request based on path and query parameters.

I think in your case you should try another approach, for example: `/api/v1/catalog/product` is more reasonable in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think best approach is to bind a HandlerInterceptor to the path "/api/vi/catalog".
Here is an example Interceptor returns 404 response if parameter is not set to product:

```
@Component
public class ProductInterceptorHandler implements HandlerInterceptor {

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    if (!request.getParameter("type").equalsIgnoreCase("product")){
        response.setStatus(404);
        // DO WHATEVER YOU WANT TO INFORM USER THAT IS INVALID
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

And you should bind it to the path inside your configuration class (in my case a SpringBootApplication that extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter):

```
@SpringBootApplication

public class ASpringApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements CommandLineRunner {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ASpringApplication.class, args);
}



@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry){
    registry.addInterceptor(new ProductInterceptorHandler()).addPathPatterns("/api/vi/catalog");
}
}
```

And finally a restcontroller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/vi/catalog", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Object> searchLocationIndexed(@RequestParam("type") String type ) throws Exception {

    return ResponseEntity.ok("ok");
}
```